# Python: Calling a function from class B in class A returns AttributeError

Tags: python, sqlite

I am new to Python and coding in general and after watching a four hour lecture, I decided to give writing a small functional application a shot.

In my application I am working with a tkinter GUI and a SQlite3 database. ClassA handles the GUI and functions that the GUI calls, while ClassB handles the database.

To insert some data the user has entered into the GUI I have defined the function add() in ClassA. The function simply calls method .insert from ClassB and then passes the data the GUI has gathered as a parameter into the .insert function in ClassB. Or so I thought..

Whenever I try I get the following traceback:

```
self.cur.execute("INSERT TO example(column1, column2, column3, column4) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", 
AttributeError: 'ClassA' object has no attribute 'cur'
```

Here's the code I am trying to run:

```
class ClassA:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title = ("Example Program")
        ...
        # REST OF GUI

    def add(self):
        ClassB.insert(self, self.entry_1.get())

class ClassB:
    def __init_(self):
        self.con = sqlite3.connect("example.db")
        self.cur = self.con.cursor()
        self.cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS example (row text)")
        self.con.commit()

    def insert(self, data):
        self.cur.execute("INSERT INTO TABLE example (row) VALUES (?)", (data))
        self.con.commit()
```

Comment: Your code is not indented properly. Is the code you are running indented correctly?

Comment: @James The code I am running is indented correctly, I have probably messed up the indentation when copying the example code over and editing this question. PyCharm also gives me no warnings related to indendation (it gives no warnings or errors at all for that matter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the first line of ClassA.add, don't pass in self. self is passed in by python as the object the method was called on. If you have `my_object.method()`, the instance of my_object would be passed into my_object method as self. [An example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/self-in-python-class/)

Something else that I'm noticing is that calling ClassB.insert should not work since
in order to use a class's methods, you need to instantiate an instance. For e.g.:

```
b = ClassB()
b.insert(a1, a2,a3, a4)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try both not passing in "self" in def add(self): and using a variable for the call. I will update once I see what happens.

Comment: I instantiated the ClassB() into a variable and after doing that, lo and behold, PyCharm gave errors related to passing "self" into the first row of def add(). Thank you for this answer, the entire application is now finished and I have learned a valuable lesson. 

I am going to edit the original question to be more easily readable and I will also upvote this answer and mark it as the solution.